# Internationalising hibernate validator messages

Tags: java, hibernate

My hibernate enity class is as follows:

```
public class AdPostFormBean {

    @NotEmpty(message="Email Id is mandatory field.") 
    @Email 
    private String email = "";

    @NotEmpty(message = "Category is mandatory field.") 
    private String category = "";//contain category id 

    @NotEmpty(message = "")
    @Length(min = 20, max = 100, message = "Ad Title accepts minimum {min}    characters")
    private String adTitle = "";

 }
```

I want to internationalise the above validator messages based on the language variable in my session i.e. I want to obtain these messages from either of the  5 different properties file based on the language variable in my session.

Could anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer from what I have understood
You can first move the hard coded text to properties files as per different languages.
Now this files will go under org.hibernate.validator. 
Your own message bundles have to be placed into the root context.

Below link will help you know more on validation messages and
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-message-interpolation

and this reference is for naming of files also just go through the source of files
https://source.jboss.org/browse/Hibernate/validator/trunk/hibernate-validator/src/main/resources/org/hibernate/validator